# IE9 jquery animation problem,

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, jquery-animate

I have an animation that slides in an image when the user clicks "chat" on the right hand side of the page, however when sliding in and out, the elemenet leaves a dotted trail in IE9, and I cannot work out why, I have `outline:0;` on my `a` element. Could somebody maybe shed some light on this for me?

http://newmead.justinbarnesconsultancy.co.uk/communicator.html

Comment: Well i Tried it in ie 9, and no line appears for me. Looks nice.
However one guess could be to add textdecoration:none; instead of outline:0; just a guess though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that might fix it would be to change the `<a>` to a `<span>` (and give it a cursor:pointer; in your css) so that IE doesn't do the highlighting thing.

Comment: that has not made a difference.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mark that up very well, have you changed your '<a>' to a span and tried again?  IE won't put a dotted line around a span.  See here in IE9 http://jsfiddle.net/qR86D/

Answer (score 1):

Or just get rid of the `<a>` and make a click function on the image directly.

```
<img id="click_me" src="whatever.png"/>
```

And as you already know (jQuery)

```
$('#click_me').click(function(){
   //Work your magic
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem seems to be when the link is active.
You culd try to set:

```
a.handle:active
{
  outline:0
}
```

once doing that you could try to set these as well:

```
a.handle:link
a.handle:visited
a.handle:hover
a.handle:active
```

Play around with it.

Hope it helps!